# Powershell script to detect OS and then display versions of SQL installed on system IF system is a server

Tags: sql, powershell, automation

Not sure why this script isn't working for me. When I try to run it it just goes to the next line and has ">>" on the left instead of PS C:\Users\username>

```
$Version = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Currentversion" -Name Productname).Productname | if ($version -like "*server*") {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.displayname -match "sql server"}
```

Does anyone see what I've done wrong here? I can verify that both parts work independantly, I seem to just be having a problem when I put them together with an if statement.

Edit: `$version = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Currentversion" -Name Productname).Productname ; if ($version -like "*server*") {    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.displayname -match "sql server"} }` 
This worked!

Comment: Because you have `if () { thing | where { }` and are missing an `}`.  and  you can't do `get-thing | if ...` at all

Comment: Is there any way to find the OS version and only on servers run the command to display SQL versions?

Comment: Do you have Active directory?

Comment: You are assigning the whole line to $version. I think you want $version = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Currentversion" -Name Productname).Productname Then your If statement on a new line. Not piping to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign $version first. That can then be used in your if statement.

```
$version = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Currentversion" -Name Productname).Productname

if ($version -like "*server*") 
{
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.displayname -match "sql server"}
}
```

Thanks, Tim.